# Randomize search result on each date

Tags: elasticsearch

So I have a scraper that scrapes jobs from company sites, and then sorted by date YYYY MM DD, but the original insertion order is maintained when this is applied, basically "grouping" the results on a given day by company. How can I keep the date sort AND on every date have the results shuffled and be randomized?

Illustration of the order of the result:

```
Job a from company 1, Job h from company 1, Job x from company 1 
then Job a from company 2, Job y from company 2, Job c from company 2
```

should be

`Job c from company 1, job a from company 3, job y from company 15`

It is crucial that the randomized order is maintained across different pages since there is paginated search for this.